# Правильная генерация url

Tags: url, веб-программирование, php, yii

Привет!

Проблема: неправильная генерация url. Как исправить?
Есть: `/panel/groups/update?id=2`.
Надо: `/panel/groups/update/2`.

Правила маршрутизации:

```
'panel/groups/<factor:\w+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups',
'panel/groups/<factor:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups',
```

Генерация (кусок от CGridView):

```
'url'=>'Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(\'/admin/backend/groups\', array(\'factor\'=>\'delete\',\'id\'=>$data["id"]))',
```

С помощью matchValue ТОЖЕ не выходит:

```
array('panel/groups/<factor:\w+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups','matchValue'=>false),
'panel/groups/<factor:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups',
```

Получаю в свою очередь урлы `admin/backend/groups/factor/index` (должно быть `/panel/groups/index`) и правильный: `/panel/groups/update/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правило #1 всех роутеров: первое совпадение выигрывает. Поменяйте строки местами.

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так в конфиге прописать:

```
'panel/<controller:(groups)>/<action:(update|delete)>/<id:\d+>'=>'admin/backend/groups/<action>'
```

и вызывайте, например, вот так:

```
'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'admin/backend/groups/delete\', array(\'id\'=>$data["id"]))'
```

при условии, что у вас в `$data["id"]` падает нужный `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте правила местами и добавьте переменное действие в роут, чтобы было:

```
'panel/groups/<factor:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups/<factor>',
'panel/groups/<factor:\w+>'=>'/admin/backend/groups/<factor>',
```